# Best approach to deploy multiple less usable applications in single infrastructure to optimize cost on Cloud

Tags: docker, kubernetes, cloud

Requirement: Cost optimization on Cloud resources

Current Scenario: I am having multiple applications that have their own infrastructure on consists of App Service, MySQL database, function, etc.

Considering these applications will be used by a few people.

My thinking is: 
 Containerizing all these web applications' servers

```
 1. Use a VM to deploy all the servers
 2. Use a Container Instanceto deploy all the servers
 3. Use Kubernetes Services to deploy all the servers
```

Questions: Which approach would be preferable and so that I can expose different IP of servers and map it to its own domain.

For Database, 
  Apart from using Elastic Pool, 
  I have no idea how to optimize these databases

I would be glad to have any suggestions thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AKS would be the way to host everything on the same platform and cut costs, but at the same time you'd need to maintain everything you host in AKS.

Elastic Pools do not work for MySQL (only Azure SQL). But you can host MySQL in AKS. To replace functions in AKS you can use [KEDA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-kubernetes-keda). You'd be able to use host based routing (preferably) or IP based routing to expose your services

Comment: Will it help in cost? If I m currently on App Service, mysql/sql db, and functions for 6-8 applications

Comment: that really depends, with AKS you pay only for the virtual machines. so the price would depend on the compute resources you need for your stuff to work properly. I'm guess if you have 6-8 app services and a mysql it's going to be really close. but the more stuff you have - the more appealing AKS is